# My calculator app is closing on button double click

Tags: android

i Have functioned a simple calculator program but the program has many errors.. the app is simply closing and buttons are not working properly sometimes

```
{

        btClr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtInput.setText(null);
                txtOutput.setText(null);
            }
        });
```

Code for all other number buttons

```
    bt0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtInput.setText((txtInput.getText() + "0"));
        }
    });
```

For functions, similar way other sub, div, mul

```
    btPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m1 = Double.parseDouble((txtInput.getText() + ""));
            fAdd = true;
            txtInput.setText(null);
        }
    });
```

Final equal function on click

```
     btEql.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                m2 = Double.parseDouble(txtInput.getText() + "");
                if (fAdd){
                    txtOutput.setText((m1 + m2 + ""));
                    fAdd = false;
                }
                if (fSub){
                    txtOutput.setText((m1 - m2 + ""));
                    fSub = false;
                }
                if (fMul){
                    txtOutput.setText((m1 * m2 + ""));
                    fMul = false;
                }
                if (fDiv){
                    txtOutput.setText((m1 / m2 + ""));
                    fDiv = false;
                }
                if (fPercent){
                    txtOutput.setText((m1 % m2 + ""));
                    fPercent = false;
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my percentage function is not working properly. Please kindly help and cannot solve this issue

Comment: what's the error in logcat? Also `m1 % m2` this is not percent but modulo. That's why it's not working as you intend to

Comment: the app is crashing on double clicking and function buttion such as plus,sub,mul etc.. but works fine for numbers

Comment: You need to add the logcat errors in your post otherwise nobody will be able to help you out an determine what's the issue. You say "double clicking" but we don't know your project like you, so you need to explain and give us as much informations as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to improve some code

1. Don't set null value in setText

   ```
   txtInput.setText(null);
   ```

   Replace with

   ```
   txtInput.setText("");
   ```
2. Check null before access/Parse

   ```
   m1 = Double.parseDouble((txtInput.getText() + ""));
   ```

   Replace with

   ```
   if(txtInput.getText() != null){
      //Do your work
   }
   ```
3. if you want to find a percentage you can use another way

   ```
   result = Math.round ((m1/ m2) * 100);
   ```